# Assign stable color to every unique value of another column of a dynamic dataset that is subsetted in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

In my `shiny` app a below I upload every time a dataset with a dynamic number of `topicLabel`. Furthermore I choose to display also a dynamic number of `topicLabel` im my plot. Im trying to assign standard colors every time that will not change when `topicLabel` is hidden and restored or other topics are added. Here is just a small sample. I tried to assign a column with colours in my dataframe after uploading it (here I give it ready) as I believe that it will not be affected by subseting later.

If you can make it work by passing another color list but adapt to the fact that the number of `topicLabel` varies it is acceptable

```
# install.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

df2<-structure(list(topicLabel = c("Advancements in Speech Recognition and Audio Processing", 
                                   "Medical Applications of ChatGPT and AI in Healthcare", "Innovative Software and Information Systems in Engineering", 
                                   "Medical Applications of ChatGPT and AI in Healthcare", "Unassigned Papers"
), x3D = c(3.1479151, -0.8278939, -0.725248, -1.076007, -0.50435966
), y3D = c(9.737644, 3.1556723, 7.265499, 3.0800967, 3.873302
), z3D = c(9.376617, 8.729877, 5.7492423, 8.762159, 8.518042), 
AssignedColor = c("red", "green", "yellow", "black", 
                  "blue")), row.names = c(144L, 318L, 582L, 588L, 662L), class = "data.frame")



# Get unique names from the 'Name' column
unique_names <- unique(df2$topicLabel)

# Assign colors to unique names
assigned_colors <- colors[1:length(unique_names)]

# Create a new column 'AssignedColor' based on the matching of names with colors
df2$AssignedColor <- assigned_colors[match(df2$topicLabel, unique_names)]



ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("3D Scatter Plot Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

        uiOutput("p1")
        
    ),
    mainPanel(
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "scatterPlot3D")
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p1<-renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = "selectedTopics",
                label = "Choose Topic Labels:",
                
                choices = list(Topics = as.list(unique(df2$topicLabel))),
                selected = unique(df2$topicLabel)[1],
                multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(
                  `actions-box` = TRUE,
                  `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                  `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                  `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                ))
    
    
  })
  
  output$scatterPlot3D <- renderPlotly({
    # Filter data based on selected topicLabels
    filteredData <- df2[df2$topicLabel %in% input$selectedTopics, ]
    
      
      # Create the 3D scatter plot with bolded hover text
      scatter3Dplot <- plot_ly(data = filteredData, x = ~x3D, y = ~y3D, z = ~z3D, color = ~as.character(topicLabel),
                               type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers",
                               marker = list(size = 3),
                               colors = ~AssignedColor
                               ) %>%
        layout(title = "3D Scatter Plot with Wrapped Title and Custom Popup by topicLabel",
               scene = list(
                 xaxis = list(title = "X Axis"),
                 yaxis = list(title = "Y Axis"),
                 zaxis = list(title = "Z Axis")
               )) %>%
        layout(legend = list(orientation = "h"),
               showlegend = FALSE)
      
      
      
      return(scatter3Dplot)
    
    
  })
  
}



# Component 3: A call to the `shinyApp` function
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When the number of topic labels change from file to file the only option I see is to create a vector of colors for all possible topic labels, i.e. not only the ones in the chosen file or dataset. Only this way can you ensure that each topic is always assigned the same color independent of which topics are included in the present data.

Comment: hmm what if my uploaded file has always the same number of topic labels but I subset it from the pickerInput? then the solutionof the previous post will work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77621270/color-dynamic-points-in-plotly-scatterplot-permanently-based-on-color-argument